# Нужен пример валидации форм в Jquery

Tags: jquery, form, валидация

Первоначально на странице проекта использовались формы для отправки данных на сервер:

```
<input type="text" id="text" size="35" pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z, ]+$" required>
```

Минимальная валидация была в виде pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z, ]+$" required

Срабатывала только в браузерах ПК.

Сейчас всё переделываю на Jquery.

Comment: Кажется, под номером 3 что-то похожее. https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-form-validation-plugins/

Comment: Буду иметь в виду. В других вопросах видел ещё упоминание про плагин jquery.validate, но неужели нет простых вариантов, чтобы не грузить кучу лишнего кода?